# javascript - trying to make an onClick alert based on id/class

Tags: javascript, onclick, alert

I'm new to programming and was wondering how to make a customized alert that shows the id or class name of the object when I click on it. My site has a picture of 8 different animals, and I want it so that every time I click on one of the animals there's an alert with "This is a (animal's name)". Why won't my javascript code below work?

should i be using "this" instead of "parama"? i don't understand whether or not to have any parameters for my function clicky.

```
var images = new Array()
images[0] = "bison"
images[1] = "frog"

function clicky(parama){
    for (entry in images){
        if (parama.attributes["name"].value === images[entry]){
            $(parama).onClick(alert("This is a" + parama.attributes["name"].value));
        } else {
            $(parama).onClick(alert("dang it");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To format a block of code on S.O., put a newline between it and the last line of text, then indent every piece of code four spaces. Backticks are only meant for `putting code in the middle of` a line of text. Using codeblocks allows for syntax highlighting and nicer whitespace

Comment: yeh i couldn't figure it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using sort of a combination of both your answers, I figured out a way to do it with a lot less code than I originally had. Check it out! (images all had classes of "pic")

```
$('.pic').click(function(){
    alert("This is a " + this.getAttribute('alt'))
});
```

Comment: you didn't mention you can use jQuery :) see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use the `title` or `alt` attribute on images instead of a JS array - that's more SEO friendly and semantic. Not to mention that `alt` is required on images to make your HTML valid - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dnysh/1/)

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for ( var i = 0, count = images.length; i < count; i++ ) {
    images[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert( this.getAttribute("alt") );
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

if you open to use jQuery - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dnysh/2/)

```
$("img").on("click", function() {
    alert( $(this).prop("alt") );
});​
```

You can use `.click()` but it's recommended to use `.on()` instead to attach different kind of event listeners to elements. jQuery also provides a shorthand for getting the properties - `.prop()`